# How to use null in join condition in linq

Tags: sql, .net, linq

I am having trouble in translating this SQL statement into linq query. I have not found a way how to use null in JOIN condition with OR.
Here is the sample SQL statement:

`SELECT a.* FROM TableA a JOIN TableB b ON (a.Id = b.Id) OR a.Id IS NULL`

What will be an equivalent linq statement? I am looking for a join condition that is the same as one in above SQL statement.

`from a in TableA join b in TableB on ??? equals ??? select a;`

I have searched for an existing post but apparently couldn't find one on this specific issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join`s are pretty picky, so you can only use them for very specific things. However, it's easy to get the same result with nested `from` statements:

```
from a in TableA 
from b in TableB 
where a.Id == b.Id or a.Id == null
select a;
```

Also, depending on what data you're really trying to find, this may be a more appropriate query:

```
from a in TableA 
where a.Id == null || TableB.Any(b => b.Id == a.Id)
select a;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. However, I needed to select a col form TableB as well in projection and therefore had to add 'from b in TableB' to the query. Since both the tables are small, cross join didn't affect much in this case. I was wondering if both the tables are very large, how this cross join would perform. I am thinking there got to a way to use such a condition in join clause.

Comment: @KhaliqueRehman: I'm guessing it wouldn't make much of a difference. In fact, I'd bet that you'd end up with exactly the same query execution plan using `from...from...where...` as you'd get with `from...join...on...`.  By the way, are you expecting more than one entry in table B to match a given entry in table A, or is it a 1-to-(zero-to-one) relationship? Also, does your LINQ provider give you navigation properties (`a.TableB`)?

Comment: Yes, I am expecting all records in table B when table A has null for matching col. I could have resolved this situation in database by creating a many to many relationship but didn't do so.
Later sometime I will compare how these two are translated in SQL.
Yes, I can use a.TableB; but I think it will create an implicit inner join.